# Why did jquery mobile switch from data-role="content" to role="main" class="ui-content"?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I googled the [role attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/role-attribute/) and it says:

> The attribute describes the role(s) the current element plays in the context of the document.

It sounds like it is used for screen readers and a very weak way of providing information about an element. e.g. role="foo" is supposed to be used in one way but there is nothing at all preventing someone from using it differently and that's why I say it's weak.

But now all old jQuery mobile code has to be changed to fit this new ~standard that is showing up in the 1.4.2 docs. My old code still works with `data-role="content"` but who knows when support will be dropped.

I mean why not let jQuery mobile users add the attribute themselves optionally. I don't understand why they would make the code more complicated and break all of the jQuery mobile code that has ever been wrote for such a weak attribute.

Comment: this change is meant to increase performance http://stackoverflow.com/a/21796410/1771795